# Updating plane track after fixing markers

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

I'm new to blender and can't seem to find a way to do this, although I'm sure it's possible.

I've tracked 4 points with markers and created a plane track. It was a bit bumpy so I've gone back and fixed up my markers but other than deleting and recreating it- I can't see a way to get the plane track to follow the updated markers?

Comment: Just select the trackers you've used and in the solve press on "Create Plane Track" for a new plane tracker using the updated information.

Comment: @cegaton is deleting and recreating the only way?